# Locust response time high latencies at the start

Tags: locust

I'm doing some load testing on a microservice application. Collected the percentile statistics and plotted them. The application is running in a shared K8s cluster. The thing I am not quite understanding is why is there a latency spike in the start? Is this an issue with a cold boot?

[Locust plot showing RT over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TfaB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this an issue with a cold boot?

Yes, this is the most likely explanation. There's no way of knowing without digging into your application and its logs though.

Most applications, especially ones that do automatic scaling, perform very poorly when suddenly hit with a large amount of load. If your actual expected user load does not have this behaviour, then maybe a slower ramp-up is more appropriate.

If you havent already read this, then maybe have a look at https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps